# Need help to understand op amp circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier

What does this op amp circuit do?

[image]

Do I understand correctly that this is some sort of divider?
What is the output of the op amp if 5v is on the inverting input?

Full circuit here:

[image: http://electro-music.com/forum/phpbb-files/th_8038_lin_vco_100.jpg]

RM: As somebody is liable to ask. This circuit is used here under the permitted category of "fair use" for the purposes of training and instruction.

Comment: Upload the image here and ask specific questions regarding *what* you do not understand - otherwise downvotes are imminent.

Comment: stack exchange uplode system is down  sorry

Comment: Where does the upwards going wire go - this circuit is incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an amplifier that gets its feedback through the 8038 internals (via the 15K resistor).

The 8038 is being powered from 0V and -15V, so the control voltage (pin 8) should go from some negative voltage up to ground or maybe a bit higher (the 1N914 will limit it to 600mV higher than V+ of the 8038).

Ignoring the "diode conducting" condition, balance of the op-amp occurs when the current through the 15K resistor (R7) equals the current through R13, so when Vin/R13 = V_pin4/R7, or V_pin4 = -Vin\$\cdot\frac{R7}{R13}\$, and it will drive its output (connected to pin 8) to achieve that condition (except if the input goes negative and the diode conducts, or the op-amp rails or current-limits)

If 5V is on the **inverting input**, then the op-amp will be railed at around -13~-14V.

If you're also asking how the circuit gets a linear VCO output from driving pin 4 to a specific voltage, I think that's a separate (and more complex question). Here's the internal schematic (and a [link](http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/an01/an013.pdf) to an app note):

[image]

Comment: And the output rail is because pin 4 would be required to produce a 750mV (not possible?) to balance the input current? Also, how can pin 8 produce 600mV over V+ when the supply is -15V to 0V? And what is the purpose of the capacitor in the feedback loop?

Comment: @sherrellbc The op-amp is powered from +/-15, so the diode limits the output to -13.5 to + 0.6 or so. The capacitor is to keep it from oscillating due to delays in the transfer function of the 8038 internals. The non inverting input is grounded so a +5 voltage on the inverting input will always rail the op-amp, because the 5V >> |Vos| and the open-loop gain * 5V is like 500,000V.

Answer (score 0):

This circuit appears to negate and integrate the input signal while the input signal is above Vout-Vd where Vd~0.6V. If the input goes below the voltage Vout-Vd, the diode would force the op-amp's output to Vout-Vd. The diode acts to prevent the op-amp from integrating a negative value for too long. Depending on the input signal frequency, it could be acting to zero out the integration.

For more info on integrating configurations look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier_applications#Integration_and_differentiation).

If the input is left at 5 volts for a long-ish amount of time, then the output will hit the negative rails and be at somewhere slightly above -15V. If it's just a short time there, then it will be the negative integral of the signal divided by RC.

This configuration could be seen as something of a low-pass filter. It has other DC restrictions stated above though.